# Python regex matching digits after text

Tags: python, regex

I am matching the movie titles which usually are in the form

```
[BLA VLA] The Matrix 1999 bla bla [bla bla]
```

My regex is

```
match = re.match("\[?.*?\](.*?)([0-9]{4})(.*)\[?.*\]?", title)
```

This works fine for most of time but it fails for movies like

```
[bla bla] 1990 The Bronx Warriors 1982
[ bl bla] 2012 2009 [ bla bla ]
```

How can i fix that

Comment: `match = re.match("\[?.*?\](.*)([0-9]{4})(.*)\[?.*\]?", title)` . You were almost there. Now the first group will match movie title, and the second group it's year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you example data, one option could be using 2 capturing groups:

```
\[[^\]]+\] (.+?) (\d{4})
```

**Explanation**

- `\[[^\]]+\]` Match part with square brackets
- `(.+?)` Capture in group 1matching a space, 1+ times any char non greedy and space
- `(\d{4})` Capture in group 2 matching 4 digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y5YwX9/2)

Answer (score 2):

If we would be having the same uppercase and lowercase patterns similar to those listed in the question, we would be starting with a simple expression, such as:

```
([A-Z][a-z]+\s)+
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4tAjFt/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"([A-Z][a-z]+\s)+"

test_str = ("[bla bla] 1990 The Bronx Warriors 1982\n"
    "[ bl bla] 2012 2009 [ bla bla ]\n"
    "[BLA VLA] The Matrix 1999 bla bla [bla bla]\n")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired or you wish to modify it, please visit [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/3FdXF3/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
re.match( r"\[.*?\]\s([\w\s]+)", title).groups()[0].strip()
```

**Code**

Going further, consider reusing your code in a function.  Here is equivalent code:

```
import re


def get_title(s):
    """Return the title from a string."""
    pattern = r"\[.*?\]\s([\w\s]+)"
    p = re.compile(pattern)
    m = p.match(s)
    g = m.groups()
    return g[0].strip()
```

**Demo**

```
get_title("[BLA VLA] The Matrix 1999 bla bla [bla bla]")
# 'The Matrix 1999 bla bla'

get_title("[bla bla] 1990 The Bronx Warriors 1982")
# '1990 The Bronx Warriors 1982'

get_title("[ bl bla] 2012 2009 [ bla bla ]")
# '2012 2009'
```

---

**Details**

See the pattern [here](https://regex101.com/r/yl598v/1):

- `\[.*?\]\s`: beyond the leading brackets and whitespace
- `([\w\s]+)`: capture optional alpha-numerals and whitespace

Comment: Sorry i didn't explain fully , i want to extract title and year in separate groups like i have in my regex

Comment: To be clear, can you explicitly add examples of sample inputs and their expected outputs?

Answer (score 0):

```
movies = '''[bla bla] 1990 The Bronx Warriors 1982
[ bl bla] 2012 2009 [ bla bla ]
[ bl bla] Normal movie title 2009 [ bla bla ]'''

import re

for movie, year in re.findall(r']\s+(.*)\s+(\d{4}).*?$', movies, flags=re.MULTILINE):
    print('Movie title: [{}] Movie year: [{}]'.format(movie, year))
```

Prints:

```
Movie title: [1990 The Bronx Warriors] Movie year: [1982]
Movie title: [2012] Movie year: [2009]
Movie title: [Normal movie title] Movie year: [2009]
```